# The derivative of an integral of a product of functions.

Tags: integration, derivatives, products

I'm trying to comprehend the following result, which is required for fractional calculus:

> Let $w(x,y)$ and $f(z)$ be two real functions, such that they both vanish at a point $a$. Then the following relation holds: 
>   $$\frac{\text d}{\text dx} \int_a^xw(x,y)f(y)\text dy=w(x)f(x)+\int_a^xf(y)\frac{\partial{w(x,y)}}{\partial{x}}\text dy.$$

My intuition for a proof points towards the integration by parts of a product of functions. But there might be a sign error if that's the case. The reference for this is *"Construction & Physical Applications Of The Fractional Calculus", Nicholas Wheeler, 1997*.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: If $w$ is a function of two variables, what is $w(x)$?

Comment: _My apologies! It was initially w(x,x), but I've reduced it to w(x) since it varies by x only._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). In general

$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {d}{dx}}\left(\int _{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt\right)=f{\big (}x,b(x){\big )}\cdot {\frac {d}{dx}}b(x)-f{\big (}x,a(x){\big )}\cdot {\frac {d}{dx}}a(x)+\int _{a(x)}^{b(x)}{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}f(x,t)\,dt.}
$$

Comment: _Indeed it is. Thank you!_